# Can CouchDB query_params in replication filter take an array?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication

I've got replication filters working great in CouchDB when the parameter is a string. However, I'm wondering if I'm able to send in an array instead. For example, my existing, working filter takes the query_param user and can be populated with a value like "tony". I'd like, however to be able to check for multiple users, such that query_params would look like

```
{
   "users": [
       "laura",
       "tony"
   ]
}
```

I've tried this in curl and I get `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}`. I'm not sure where the invalid JSON is.

The request via curl looks like:

```
  curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -X POST http://example.com:5984/_replicate  \
  -d '{"source":"http://example.com:5984/db1","target":"http://example.com:5984/db2", "filter":"repfilter/users", "query_params":{"users":["laura","tony"]}'
```

In my filter code, I check for the existence of the document field `userID` in the `users` array from the query params.

```
 "users": "function(doc,req){ if(req.query.users.indexOf(doc.userID) >= 0){return true;} return false;   }"
```

Is this not possible in Couch or am I doing something wrong? Should I just use a comma-separated string instead?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the best way to accomplish an array will be doing something like this:

```
?users="laura"&users="tony"
```

I'm not 100% positive how erlang parses this type of querystring, so if that fails, a comma-separated list is probably going to be simpler:

```
?users="laura,tony"
```

Just add the following in your fn:

```
var users = req.query.users.split(',');
```